# Is eating refregerated home cooked food daily bad for health?

Tags: nutrition, cancer, food-safety, lifestyle, plastic

I cook food on Sunday in bulk quantity, enough to last me lunch and dinner till Wednesday (sometimes Thursday if I had to skip for outside food in between).
I separate everyday meals in rubber maid plastic containers and keep it frozen in the refrigerator. When I want to eat it, I heat it in microwave.
I have been following this schedule everyday and would like to know if this has any adverse effects on my health(or rather anyone's health in general)?

Answer (score 3):

Prepared food is typically good for 3-4 days in the refrigerator
[food safety guidelines](https://www.foodsafety.gov/keep/charts/storagetimes.html)

Frozen is is even longer.

It would be cooled (not frozen) in a normal refrigerator.

Healthy depends on the food.  Home prepared food can be healthier than prepared food (especially fast food) that can have a lot of fat and salt.